# Div not getting same height of the sibling previous div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm building a list of boxes that can be scrolled by the user. Each item can be deleted if the user clicks on the buttons:

[image]

Here is my current code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.Container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
}

.ItemsContainer {
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.ItemContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #202020;
  width: 100%;
}

.ItemContent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.ItemHeader {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #202020;
}

.ItemValue {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  min-height: 20px;
}

.ItemButton {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: flex-end;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div>HEADER</div>
  <div class="ItemsContainer">
    <div class="ItemContainer">
      <div class="ItemContent">
        <div class="ItemHeader">
          <div>LINE 1</div>
          <div>Line 1 comment</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemValue">Value 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="ItemButton">X</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ItemContainer">
      <div class="ItemContent">
        <div class="ItemHeader">
          <div>LINE 2</div>
          <div>Line 2 comment</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemValue">Value 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="ItemButton">X</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ItemContainer">
      <div class="ItemContent">
        <div class="ItemHeader">
          <div>LINE 3</div>
          <div>Line 3 comment</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemValue">Value 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="ItemButton">X</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm getting a strange behaviour, as the rightmost div that contains the "X" button (red div) is not going full height (the height of the main div - blue bordered).

I'm using flex as the main strategy to build this and wanna keep it if possible.

Comment: just remove the `align-self: flex-end` from `.itemButton` ?

Answer (score 1):

Delete `align-self: flex-end;` from the button.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.Container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
}

.ItemsContainer {
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.ItemContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #202020;
  width: 100%;
}

.ItemContent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.ItemHeader {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #202020;
}

.ItemValue {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  min-height: 20px;
}

.ItemButton {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div>HEADER</div>
  <div class="ItemsContainer">
    <div class="ItemContainer">
      <div class="ItemContent">
        <div class="ItemHeader">
          <div>LINE 1</div>
          <div>Line 1 comment</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemValue">Value 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="ItemButton">X</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ItemContainer">
      <div class="ItemContent">
        <div class="ItemHeader">
          <div>LINE 2</div>
          <div>Line 2 comment</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemValue">Value 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="ItemButton">X</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ItemContainer">
      <div class="ItemContent">
        <div class="ItemHeader">
          <div>LINE 3</div>
          <div>Line 3 comment</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ItemValue">Value 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="ItemButton">X</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, yes... what a dumb mistake... I've meant `justify-self`. Thanks for helping...